How to make the viewBox of an SVG Overlay the same size as the image underneath?
I would like to build a small GUI using the Python NiceGUI Library.
For my application I split the interface into two columns using the grid element. This works fine. On the left there are cards with checkboxes to see the overlays.
In the right column I insert an image of a t-shirt and would like to overlay the image with a small red box that marks a hole in the t-shirt. The coordinates of the box are given in a list that works with the original image size. (I've tested this using plt.imshow()).
I have figured out how to display the viewBox, draw the red box and have it overlay the image.
Just the size of the ovelay doesn't match the size of the image yet. Fo some reason there is an unspecified amount of padding around the overlay that I cannot seem to access or get id of.
I think this should be fixable using the .props() .style() or .classes() methods or the width of the columns, but I don't know which one to use and how. For my application it doesn't matter how large the image and the view box are, as long as they are the same so that the red box is at the correct spot.
I'm not fluent in html or CSS, so there might be mistakes in those parts of the code that I may not know about. (I'm also open to style improvements.)
It seems to me that the example that NiceGUI gives in their documentation has a similar issue.
(see https://nicegui.io/documentation/section_audiovisual_elements#captions_and_overlays)
If you manually inspect the element of the airplane picture and manually change cx to 960 and cy to 638 (dimensions of the view box), the circle appears around the airplane which makes more sense to me.
Here's a small working example:
(any image should work but this is where i got mine:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/225367896573)
from nicegui import ui

complete_im = plt.imread("test_file_large.jpg")
y_dim, x_dim = complete_im.shape[1], complete_im.shape[0]

tile = complete_im[355:385, 895:935]  # This was saved to 'test_hole_3.jpg'

tile_files = ['test_hole_3.jpg']
tile_ids = (355, 385, 895, 935)
tile_dims = (30, 40)

with ui.grid(columns=2).classes("w-auto").style():
    with ui.card():
        ui.image(tile_files[0])
        ui.space()
        checkbox_0 = ui.checkbox('Show hole')
        checkbox_0.value = True

    with ui.image('test_file_large.jpg').style('object-position: top right;'):
        # .props('fit=contain'):
        svg_code = f'''
                  <svg viewBox="0 0 {y_dim} {x_dim}" width="100%" height="100%" 
                       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="color: transparent;">
                  <rect width="{str(tile_dims[1])}" height="{str(tile_dims[0])}" 
                      x="{str(tile_ids[2])}" y="{str(tile_ids[0])}" 
                      style="stroke:red;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:0.0;stroke-opacity:0.99" />
                      </svg>'''

        ui.html(svg_code).bind_visibility_from(checkbox_0, 'value')

ui.run()


In order to let the SVG fill the full image size, you can add a "w-full" class like this:
with ui.image('https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/airplane-sky_DYPWDEEILG.jpg'):
    ui.html('''
        <svg viewBox="0 0 960 638" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="445" cy="300" r="100" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
        </svg>
    ''').classes('w-full bg-transparent')

(I'm using the example from the NiceGUI website, since your code needs a bit more work to get running.)
By the way, you correctly spotted a mistake in the official example. We'll fix it with the next website update.
Apart from that, ui.interactive_image might be better suited than a regular ui.image, since it comes with a correctly scaled SVG out of the box:
ui.interactive_image(
    'https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/airplane-sky_DYPWDEEILG.jpg',
    content='<circle cx="445" cy="300" r="100" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />',
)


Thanks for the help!
I'd thought about using the interactive_image(), but I do not know how to bind the visibility of the svg content to the checkbox there.
Using the .classes('w-full') helped to get the viewBox sized up, but the red boxes still don't match up with the image tiles. They are off by different values for the different boxes (around 10-50) and I still have to do some digging to find out what exactly is happening there.

So after taking a closer look I have discovered that using a an svg overlay in a with ui.image() with .classes('w-full') still leads to an automatic padding being implemented around the edge of the image. This results in the overlay being too small and centred. If you take the svg out of the with statement it sizes correctly but is placed underneath the image. I've kind of given up on trying to fix this and might just take a different approach to the task all together.
